# Generate unique sessionId with Express Cookie-Session

Tags: node.js, express, cookie-session

I'm using `node/express.js` with `cookie-session` in my application.

Currently, when a user logs in a cookie is stored in their browser with a value, for example: `session: ABC123`. If the user logs out, the cookie is deleted. When the user logs back in, the same cookie and value are stored in the browser `session: ABC123`.

[image]

I am getting the same session `user_sid` whenever i login.

i want to randomize the session `user_sid` every time the user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of a session id with the `cookie-session` package.

In the typical scenario where the session data is stored on the server, a session id is generated that maps to a given user session data. This is this session id that is kept in the session cookie.

With the cookie-session package however, the session data itself is stored in the cookie - as opposed to on the server -, so there is no need for such a mapping or a session id at all. So in effect and unless the session data is actually updated from one session to another, the session cookie will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call session.regenerate() when the user successfully login, that will do what you want and also address session fixation attack

Comment: btw i am not using express-session in my app. I am using cookie-session. Is there any way to regenerate session in cookie-session ?

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were also using express-session. With bare cookie-session, then no straightforward way that I know of :/